# AngularJS - how to get all elements by querySelector and disable links

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make a simple step-by-step wizard.

HTML code for that (in index.html) looks like

```
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="/" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" id="step-1">1</a>
        <p>Start</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="/registration" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled" id="step-2">2</a>
        <p>Registration</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="/tutorial" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled" id="step-3">3</a>
        <p>Tutorial</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="/thank-you" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled" id="step-4">4</a>
        <p>Finish</p>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
```

Code above work fine when was triggered by jQuery which looks like
      function stepnext(n){

```
function step(n){
    if(n != 0){
        $(".stepwizard-row a").removeClass('btn-primary');
        $(".stepwizard-row a").addClass('btn-default');
        $('.stepwizard-row #step-'+n+'').removeClass('btn-default');
        $('.stepwizard-row #step-'+n+'').addClass('btn-primary');
    }
}
```

but I have moved it to each step controller and triggers it as

```
var stepReset = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.stepwizard-row a' ) );
stepReset.removeClass('btn-primary');
stepReset.addClass('btn-default');

var stepActive = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#step-1' ) );
stepActive.removeClass('btn-default');
stepActive.addClass('btn-primary');
```

and so on for each `#step-X`

It works fine for selecting on each step for `btn-primary` but then when I follow to next step like from 2 to 3 is not reseting class from step 2 to `btn-default` just taking effect on first element from `.stepwizard-row a` which is step#1.

My question is how I can select all DOM elements for `.stepwizard-row a`?

Another question is related to have links "disabled" until landed or passed particular step. I have set them to `disabled="disabled"` but AngularJS let me click on them and skip steps.

Comment: for disabled="disabled" use ng-disabled  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: @Knitesh `ngDisabled` it makes button disabled statement but clicking on it still effect to do routing to that URL

Comment: @Knitesh I have kind of solved `ngDisable` case but it lead to another problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316395/angularjs-and-redirect-within-factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually querying elements from the DOM is rarely needed in AngularJS, and in the rare cases where you need this functionality a directive is more suited.

A better way to do this is to use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) and add/remove the `btn-default` and `btn-primary` classes based on an expression, like so:

```
<a href="/" type="button" class="btn btn-circle" ng-class="{'btn-default': notCurrentStep(), 'btn-primary': currentStep()}" id="step-1">1</a>
```

You can then implement the `notCurrentStep` and `currentStep` functions in your controller based on your needs.

As for the `disabled` attribute and as @Knitesh mentioned, it's better to use [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) so that you can dynamically add/remove the `disabled` attribute based on an expression.

Comment: `ngDisabled` it makes button disabled statement but clicking on it still effect to do routing to that URL

Comment: I have kind of solved `ngDisable` case but it lead to another problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316395/angularjs-and-redirect-within-factory

Answer (score 1):

A similar and easier approach would be :

```
<a href="/" type="button" class="btn btn-circle" ng-class="{'btn-default': step === 1, 'btn-primary': step !== 1 }" id="step-1">1</a>
```

And in your Controller:

```
function currentStep (step) { $scope.step = step; }
```

Comment: Should I use `$rootScope` as is not taking any effect on `index.html` when executed from particular controller (per step).