# AngularJS and redirect within factory

Tags: angularjs

I have a factory from where I want to redirect to another app location
'use strict';

```
myApp.factory('wizard', ['$rootScope', '$location', function ($rootScope, $location){

    return {

        doSteps: function(step){

            switch (step){
                case 1 :
                    $location.path('/');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                    break;              
                case 2 :
                    $location.path('start');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    $location.path('tutorial');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    $location.path('finish');
                    $rootScope.$apply()
                    break;                  
                default:
                    $location.path('/');
                    $rootScope.$apply();
            }
        }
    }

}]);
```

which is suppose to be triggered by a button link in `index.html` file

```
<a href="" ng-click="wizard.doSteps(1)" type="button" class="btn btn-circle" ng-class="{'btn-default': step !== 1, 'btn-primary': step === 1 }" id="step-1">1</a>
```

and so on based on a step

Controller is loading `wizard` factory but somehow I'm not able to execute function from that factory on `ng-click`.

Question is if I'm doing this right or not?

Comment: try `ng-click="doStepts(1)"` in `html` and in your controller `$scope.doSteps=function(i){wizard.doSteps(i) }`

Comment: @UsmanRana that did the job as well required to remove `$rootScope.$apply();` from the factory in that case. You can post it as a solution.

Comment: glad to know if that resolved your query

Comment: you can accept the answer if it resolved your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ng-click="doStepts(1)"
```

in html 
and in your controller

```
$scope.doSteps=function(i){wizard.doSteps(i) }
```